# Uploading a file to Sharepoint Via webservices without a page refresh using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, sharepoint, jquery-ui, wss

I am trying to create a wizard using jquery (fill in a dialog of info, press next, dialog changes but page does not refresh). During this process I would like to upload a file to a document library. I do not wish to reload the page. Is this possible? How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Not really a question, more a plea for a full solution. Why not break the question up and tackle them one at a time.

Comment: I suppose the question is simply "can I upload a file to sharepoint without reloading the page?" the rest is just setting the scene. The rest of the stuff I can do fine.

Comment: Yup there are various jquery upload plugins or easy to do yourself using an hidden iframe that you post to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use uploadify plugin [here](http://www.uploadify.com/), which uses a flash component to upload files and it provides events for almost every state of uploading, so you can fire your functions whenever you want for changing content showing alerts etc...

As redsquare says there are also other plugins, but i used this one in a project and it works pretty well.

Hope it helps,

Sinan.